# DBLookUpCombobox Duvida - Delphi 6

Tags: banco-de-dados, delphi, combobox

Bom dia.

Estou usando o Delphi 6 e estou com uma dúvida, eu tenho uma tabela de alunos vinculadas a uma tabela de disciplinas, e essas disciplinas são exibidas dentro de um DBLookUpCombobox, só que quando eu seleciono um determinado aluno, gostaria que a disciplina que ele está vinculado já aparecesse na caixa dessa Combobox, sem precisar dessa caixa porque ela não aparece de primeira, apenas quando clica e mostra a lista de disciplinas.

Att.,

Gustavo.

Answer (score 1):

Para isso você precisa configurar o DBLookUpComboBox corretamente:

- ListSource => O DataSource que fornece os dados da tabela "Disciplinas"
- ListField => O campo na tabela "Disciplinas" que mostra o nome da disciplina.
- KeyField => O campo Chave Primária da tabela "Disciplinas".

Caso queira modificar o campo Disciplina na tabela "Alunos", precisas configurar também:

- DataSource => O DataSource que receberá os dados, no caso o "Alunos".
- DataField => O campo Chave Estrangeira que receberá o valor de KeyField.